# Why can't a constant field be of non-built-in struct type in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, constants

```
class T
{
    enum E { }
    struct S { }
    interface I { }
    delegate void D();
    class C { }

    const E e = new E();
    //const S s = default(S); // ERROR
    const I i = default(I);
    const D d = default(D);
    const C c = default(C);

    const int x = 10;
    const string y = "s";

    private void MyMethod(
        E e = new E(),
        S s = default(S), // NO ERROR
        I i = default(I),
        D d = default(D),
        C c = default(C),
        int x = 10,
        string y = "s")
    { }
}
```

All of the above are possible except for the constant field of `struct` type.

I can see why the non-`string` reference types would default to the only literal expression they can represent - `null` - but if I'm not mistaken the default value of a struct is an instance of the struct with all its fields set to their default value, basically `memset(0)`. Also, for the default arguments of the method `MyMethod` the compiler has no complaints. So, why is it that a `const struct` field is not possible?

Is there a reason why or is it just the way C# was written? Oh and by the way, what's the idea of allowing enum types to have a default constructor?

(Question originally found [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/144269-why-can%27t-constant-field-non-built-struct-type.html), where it didn't get a real answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fundamentally, true *constant* fields need to be representable directly in IL as metadata, which means: limiting to a set of known types that *work directly in IL*. You *could* say that you can express a "constant" via a constructor call and substitute that constructor call whenever the constant is used, etc, but:

1. that would be simulating something very close to `static readonly`, which already exists and can be used
2. it would not be provably *constant* - since your custom type could do anything internally

Basically, just use `static readonly` in your case:

```
static readonly S s = default(S);
```

In the case of enums: all value types both *have* a default constructor (in C# terms) and *don't have* a default constructor (in IL terms). Schrödinger's constructor! All the semi-existent default constructor means is "initialize this to zero", and it works for *any* value type (it is the `initobj` IL instruction). Actually, in C# you can also do this in two other ways for enums: `default(TheEnum)`, and `0` - since the literal `0` works for ***any*** enum.

Comment: No rules without exceptions :) - http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/22/when-is-a-constant-not-a-constant-when-its-a-decimal/

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yeah, I remember that post - a very interesting one; but at least the compiler folks know for sure that `decimal` is going to be reasonably well behaved (point "2."), so having compiler support for silently substituting `const` into `static readonly` (as per point "1.") is very convenient ;p (especially with `[DecimalConstant]`, which makes the compiler do compile-time substitutions, etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell But isn't it a bit quirky that it works for default function parameters (where you also can't use constructors), but not for fields? Since value types don't have a default constructor in IL other than `initobj` I thought it might've worked just fine. Can't do no funny things inside the default constructor after all...

Comment: @johv actually, the question of "do value-type default constructors exist?" is much more complex, and every so often it comes up for discussion again - they might even have raised it again for C# 6, I can't remember. So `new SomeValueType()` might *actually* means something different in the future. However, `default(SomeValueType)` is unambiguous.

Comment: @MarcGravell I guess my more specific question is why `default(S)` can't work *directly in IL* for any struct, not just for built-ins. It is, as you say, unambiguous. And why does it work for default-args?

Comment: @johv the default answer as to "why doesn't it..." is: because it wasn't worth designing, implementing, testing, documenting, translating and supporting

Comment: @MarcGravell It would be nice if compiler generates itself a class, for example `<>c__ConstStructs` with `static readonly` field and then places a link on it in the method. It could provide much better readability, especially for small methods.

Answer (score 2):

The designers of C# seem to take the viewpoint that the language should forbid constructs which would have semantics that were well-defined but didn't seem to be useful, especially if such constructs would represent things the designers didn't think people should be doing.

For example, C# forbids the use of sealed types as generic constraints.  If class `Foo` isn't sealed, then a declaration `class Bar<T> where T:Foo` will declare a generic class family `Bar<>` for which the `T` would have to be `Foo` or something derived from it.  Semantically, there's no reason that construct couldn't have the exact same meaning even if `Foo` were a sealed type; to be sure, *unless `Foo` were to change*, there wouldn't be any way `T` could be anything other than `Foo`, and the designers of C# would probably say that the code should simply use `Foo` rather than `T` [though if `Foo` were ever unsealed, the meaning of the generic code would no longer match the code that specified `Foo`].

Likewise, I suspect that while there wouldn't have been any particular problem with C# allowing a value type to declare a constant equal to the the default value of that type, the normal purpose of constants is to provide a single patch point for things that might need to change.  Any code which declared `const MyPoint = Default(Point);` to declare a default location of (0,0) may have been up a creek if it became necessary to have a different default value.

On the other hand, the fact that C# doesn't allow the declaration of non-default-valued constants of non-primitive value types other than `Decimal` doesn't mean that C# wouldn't be cable of passing through the values of constants declared in other assemblies if the language designers had chosen to allow that.  If C# had allowed value-type constants declared in other assemblies to be used as value-type constants in C#, then if it became necessary to use some value other than the default for a `Point` constant, it would be possible to add to the assembly a reference to a CIL module which defined a `Point` constant containing the sequence of byte which would represent the necessary coordinates, and then have the C# module use the constant from the CIL assembly.

I disagree with the idea that `static readonly` should be considered a 100% adequate substitute for `const`, since values of constants may be used in contexts where values of static readonly variables cannot.  Still, the fact that C# is unwilling to consider value-type constants from other modules to be legitimate constant expressions unless the types in question are ones it knows about would greatly limit the usefulness of being able to define constants of arbitrary value types.

**Addendum**

Discussions elsewhere have brought up a more general problem with value-type constants: they're stored as a sequence of bytes, which means that their meaning will be very dependent upon implementation details of the type in question; if later versions of a type store things differently, there would be no mechanism to prevent the byte sequence from being totally misinterpreted.  As a simple example, if one version of a type `Point` had `int` fields `X` and `Y` in that order, but later version changed the sequence to `Y`, `X`, then a `Point` constant which was compiled with X=1 Y=2 would be interpreted as having Y=1 X=2.